# Can't position bar buttons on top?

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard, uibarbuttonitem, xcode-storyboard

I'm just trying to set up a simple storyboard. I have a `View Controller` embedded in a `Navigation Controller`, and it is the starting view for the app. I added a full-page `Table View` and a `Table View Cell` inside that.

Then I wanted to add two `Bar Button Items` to the top, but when I drag them in, that's where the trouble is. When I drag it onto the top bar, it creates a new bar at the bottom and attaches there instead. When I go to the Document Outline and manually drag it under `Navigation Item` in the `View Controller`, then it works and goes to the upper right.

But then there's no way for me to add a second `Bar Button Item` to the upper left-- when I drag one in, it goes to the bottom, and if I try dropping it under `Navigation Item` in the Document Outline along with the first one, it just ceases to exist, as though only one `Bar Button Item` were allowed.

What am I doing wrong? This has worked fine in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes storyboards have bad days and xCode has bugs. Then code comes to rescue:

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
showCalendar.frame = CGRectMake( 0, 0, 40, 30 );
[showCalendar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"calendar"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[showCalendar addTarget:self action:@selector(METHOD CALL) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```

You can repeat the process for adding another button on the left.

Comment: I ended up fixing it by deleting the items in the view and placing them all again in a slightly different order (had to repeat this 3x before I got it totally right). But I'm sure this works too!